# How can I disable SQUID:UnusedProtectedMethod in Sonar for a class or method?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a couple Hadoop map and reduce classes that override protected methods.  Sonar flags these with:

```
Unused protected method
Plugin: squid    Key: UnusedProtectedMethod
```

I know there's a fix in Sonar that addresses this and that at some point my organization will use a version with that fix.  In the meantime, I'd like to disable the warning.  I've tried:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedProtectedMethod")
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("SQUID.UnusedProtectedMethod")
```

to no avail.

@SuppressWarnings works for PMD issues, @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(value = "blah") works for findbugs issues.  Is there another variant for squid issues, or is it just not supported yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:UnusedProtectedMethod")
```

See also [SonarQube Java Plugin FAQ - SuprressWarnings](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ#JavaFAQ-SuppressWarnings)

This has been implemented in the SonarQube Java plugin version 2.8.

Comment: So, it's just an issue of case?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is a bit different than the examples you tried. Also I think this wasn't implemented when you asked the question in 2012.

Comment: (a) Looks like your link is broken... (b) As I understand, some Squid checking is at the bytecode level, where this annotation won't appear; is Sonar clever enough to still pick up the annotation from source in such cases? This is why FindBugs introduced `SuppressFBWarnings` with runtime retention, although I doubt `SuppressFBWarnings` works for non-FindBugs (e.g. squid) violations.

Comment: @Kidburla (a) I updated it. Thanks :-) (b) Good question. My guess is that SonarQube could still ignore a warning from byte code analysis when linking it to the line number in the source later. But I don't know.

Comment: @Kidburla Annotations are compiled into bytecode: [Annotations in bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368137/how-is-java-annotation-represented-in-java-bytecode?rq=1). See also [AnnotationDefault attribute in bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32995220/1548776).

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ Annotations are only compiled into bytecode if the annotation is marked with an appropriate retention meta-annotation, which this one isn't.

Comment: @Kidburla I see, `SuppressWarnings` has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`, which speaks for itself. Now I understand what you said earlier about `SuppressFBWarnings` … Would using `@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings` be useful?

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ The `SuppressWarnings` variant you refer to is actually identical to `SuppressFBWarnings` in terms of how it is used (i.e. used by FindBugs, which only works at the bytecode level.) The only reason there are two such classes is so that both can easily be used in the same class. When an analyzer looks for an annotation on a class, it is looking for a fully-qualified annotation. (When class files are assembled, all imported references are translated to fully-qualified ones.) In this case, squid is only looking for `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` rather than the findbugs variant.

Answer (score 3):

I found that Squid supports only "all."  From the squid plugin source, in SuppressWarningsAnnotationUtils.java:

```
private static final String VALUE = "\"all\"";
...


  public static boolean isSuppressAllWarnings(DetailAST ast) {
    DetailAST suppressWarningsAnnotation = getSuppressWarningsAnnotation(ast);
    if (suppressWarningsAnnotation != null) {
      DetailAST warningHolder = findWarningsHolder(suppressWarningsAnnotation);
      for (DetailAST warning = warningHolder.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.EXPR); warning != null; warning = warning.getNextSibling()) {
        if (warning.getType() == TokenTypes.EXPR) {
          DetailAST fChild = warning.getFirstChild();
          if (fChild.getType() == TokenTypes.STRING_LITERAL) {
            String text = warning.getFirstChild().getText();
            if (VALUE.equals(text)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

There's discussion here: [Support the annotation "@SuppressWarnings" at class and method level](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1760?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

Comment: And this doesn't even work reliably on Sonar 3.4.1. This issue of not being able to suppress false positives *in the code* (instead of via the Sonar web GUI), prevents us from using squid in an enterprise environment.