# how is java annotation represented in java bytecode

Tags: java, annotations, bytecode, decompiling, declarative

I tried to decompile a .class file that contains JUnit tests.
I read the byte code, but I did not see any clue of the @Test annotation(it's used in the java source code).

As metadata, how are annotations represented in bytecode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Annotations appear just before the byte code of the thing it is associated with. If you are not seeing the annotations it could be an old de-compiler (most of them are)

Comment: I used JBVD. What are the new ones that are able to decompile annotations?

Comment: I use ObjectWeb's ASM, this is not a de-compiler but reads everything which is there.